# Firewall-cmd hangs after yum update

Tags: centos7, firewalld

When I use `firewall-cmd` it hangs, I just did a update with `yum` and got updates for `python (2.7.5)` and the `kernel`.

I use CentOS 7, when I do `sudo systemctl status firewalld.service` I got: `Active: active (running)`.

When I do: `ps aux | grep fire` it shows:

```
root     15616  0.0  0.4 249448 20088 ?        Ss   22:18   0:00 /usr/bin/python -Es /usr/sbin/firewalld
root     17687  0.0  0.0 335772   472 ?        Ssl  jul10   0:00 /usr/bin/python -Es /usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --nopid
```

How can I solve the hanging of firewall-cmd?

Comment: Not any answer by any means, but does firewall-cmd --list-all hang as well?

Comment: `firewall-cmd -h` works fine, but.. `firewall-cmd --list-all` and adding rules hangs.

Comment: Does the box resolve DNS queries successfully, incase there are delays in name resolution, giving symptoms of a hang. Also, worth looking to see if all the interfaces of the box are up and active.

Comment: Can you give examples how I can do that @yetdot? Are you sure the hang isn't related to python?

Comment: It could very well be Python related, seems historically there have been few bugs if you search google. To do the DNS resolution, you can check the file /etc/resolv.conf is have nameserver entry in it, then run the nslookup command with some name eg google.com for example. You should see valid Google public IPs as a result of that. For the network interfaces, you can run the IP command "ip addr". I think there is an ip show dev or show link or something similar might also help. The object of these two was to help troubleshoot if it is indeed network issue rather than related to the yum update.

Comment: Not sure if that helps in any way, but I've centos7 with Python 2.7.5 on it and had no problems pulling up firewall-cmd with any of the command line parameters. Can you see if SELinux is running or not? I have it running and still have no problems. It might help if you look in /var/log/messages to see if there are any log entries related to firewalld.